# IIS returns 404 when trying to access static files on certain file types

Tags: iis, web.config, http-status-code-404, static-files, iis-8.5

I have a specific file type of .notebook that IIS is blocking. I tried going into request filtering and adding .notebook with allow set to true, but I still get the 404. Anything else in this folder will download, just this one type is being blocked.

I'm not pushing the download via headers, this is typing in the URL of the file directly.

For reference this is the relevant section that was added to the web.config when I made the change

```
<security>
    <requestFiltering allowDoubleEscaping="false">
        <fileExtensions>
            <add fileExtension=".notebook" allowed="true" />
        </fileExtensions>
    </requestFiltering>
</security>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add a MIME type to the IIS config for the .notebook extension.  You'll have to find out exactly what the mime type is to use.  Maybe `application/x-smarttech-notebook`.

Comment: That was it, I knew it was something simple